# Como puedo unir tablas sin relacion con Criteria API?

Tags: java, criteria-api

Estoy recién entrando en el mundo de las consultas con criteria y me toca hacer una que tiene que unir una tabla sin relación , he probado algunas formas pero no he tenido éxito.

Esta es la estructura que estoy creando, lo que esta comentado aun no veo porque no funciona, pero lo mas que me complica es como hacer la relación con la tabla Semana

```
public ResultWithSqlQuery getWeeklyHistoricalSeriesInformation(ParamsInfoSeriesHistoricas params)
            throws DataAccessException {
    List<ResultSemanalSerieHistoricaPrecioMariscos> resultado = new ArrayList<ResultSemanalSerieHistoricaPrecioMariscos>();
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TNotMerProdMar.class, "notMerProd");
           
    ProjectionList proj = Projections.projectionList();
    proj.add(Projections.sqlProjection("DATEPART(week, (mer_fec)) as dateWeek", new String[] { "dateWeek" },
            new Type[] { ShortType.INSTANCE }));
    /* proj.add(Projections.sqlProjection("DATEADD(dd, 6, fecha) as dateDay", new String[] { "dateDay" },
            new Type[] { ShortType.INSTANCE }));  */
            proj.add(Projections.groupProperty("notMerProd.fecha"), "fecha")
            .add(Projections.sum("notMerProd.volumen"), "volumen")
            .add(Projections.min("notMerProd.precioMinimo"), "precioMinimo")
            .add(Projections.max("notMerProd.precioMaximo"), "precioMaximo")
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("uni.descripcion"));
    
    /* Criteria criteriaSemana = currentSession().createCriteria(Semana.class,"semnana");
    criteriaSemana.add(Property.forName("semana").in(criteria)); */
    
    //JOINS
    criteria.createAlias("notMerProd.unidad", "uni");
            //.createAlias("semana", "sem");

    //WHERE
    criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DATEPART( yy, {alias}.mer_fec ) =" + params.getYearTermino()));
    //criteria.add(Restrictions.between("DATEPART(week, notMerProd.mer_fec)", params.getWeekOrMonthInicio(), params.getWeekOrMonthTermino()));
    //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("notMerProd.empresa", ConstantPreciosMar.EMP_COD));
    //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("notMerProd.origen", params.getProductIds()));
    //criteriaSemana.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("DATEPART( yy, {alias}.mer_fec ) =" + "semana.temporada"));
    
criteria.setProjection(proj);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ResultSemanalSerieHistoricaPrecioMariscos.class));
resultado = (List<ResultSemanalSerieHistoricaPrecioMariscos>) this.getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(criteria);       

    ResultWithSqlQuery salida = new ResultWithSqlQuery();
salida.setResult(resultado);
salida.setSql(UtilApp.toSql(criteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession())));
return salida;
}
```

Esta es la consulta SQL estoy trabajando con Sybase, con la unión de la T_unidad no tengo problemas logró hacer el join.

```
    DATEPART(week, mer_fec),
    fecha,
    DATEADD(dd, 6, fecha) ,
    SUM(mer_vol),
    MIN(mer_pre_min),
    MAX(mer_pre_max),
    uni_des
FROM
    odepa..T_not_mer_prod_mar,
    odepa..T_semana,
    odepa..T_unidad
WHERE
    DATEPART(yy, mer_fec) = 2011
    AND DATEPART(week, mer_fec) BETWEEN 1 AND 19 
    AND mer_emp_cod = 3019
    AND mer_ori_cod = 919
    AND temporada = DATEPART(yy, mer_fec)
    AND semana = DATEPART(week, mer_fec)
    AND mer_uni_cod = uni_cod
GROUP BY
    datepart(week,
    mer_fec),
    fecha,
    DATEADD(dd, 6, fecha) ,
    uni_des
ORDER BY
    fecha,
    DATEADD(dd, 6, fecha)
```

Esto es lo que me devuelve la consola y como va quedando la consulta creada con criteria, como se ve se genera bien el join con la tabla T_unidad.

```
        DATEPART(week,
        (mer_fec)) as dateWeek,
        this_.mer_fec as y1_,
        sum(this_.mer_vol) as y2_,
        min(this_.mer_pre_min) as y3_,
        max(this_.mer_pre_max) as y4_,
        uni1_.uni_des as y5_ 
    from
        odepa.dbo.T_not_mer_prod_mar this_ 
    inner join
        odepa.dbo.T_unidad uni1_ 
            on this_.mer_uni_cod=uni1_.uni_cod 
    where
        DATEPART( yy, this_.mer_fec ) =2011 
    group by
        this_.mer_fec,
        uni1_.uni_des
```

La entidad de la tabla Semana

```
@Table(name = "T_semana", catalog = Constant.CATALOG_ODEPA, schema = Constant.SCHEMA_DBO)
public class Semana implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7113166380161050959L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;

    @Column(name = "fecha")
    private Calendar fecha;

    @Column(name = "semana")
    private Byte semana;

    @Column(name = "temporada")
    private Short temporada;

    @Column(name = "mes_asociado")
    private Byte mesAsociado;

    @Column(name = "quincena")
    private Byte quincena;

    @Transient
    private Calendar fechaTo;
    
    ....
```

La entidad para la tabla Unidad

```
@Table(name = "T_unidad", catalog = Constant.CATALOG_COMERCIO, schema = Constant.SCHEMA_DBO)
@Cacheable
public class Unidad implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1248864768216310116L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uni_cod")
    private Byte codigo;

    @Column(name = "uni_des")
    private String descripcion;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unidad", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ProductoUnidad> productoUnidad;
    ....
```

La entidad de la tabla T_not_mer_prod_mar

```
@Table(name = "T_not_mer_prod_mar", catalog = Constant.CATALOG_ODEPA, schema = Constant.SCHEMA_DBO)
@Cacheable
public class TNotMerProdMar implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3558943904627207982L;

    @Id
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "mer_fec")
    private Calendar fecha;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_emp_cod")
    private Empresa empresa;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_ori_cod")
    private Origen origen;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_eco_cod")
    private TEstCon estadoConsumo;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_var_cod")
    private Variedad variedad;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_tip_cod")
    private Tipificacion tipificaion;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_uni_cod")
    private Unidad unidad;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mer_prc_cod")
    private TNotMerPrc merPrcCod;

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER, pattern = "######")
    @Column(name = "mer_vol")
    private BigDecimal volumen;

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER, pattern = "#####")
    @Column(name = "mer_pre_min")
    private BigDecimal precioMinimo;

    @NumberFormat(style = Style.NUMBER, pattern = "#####")
    @Column(name = "mer_pre_max")
    private BigDecimal precioMaximo; 

   ....
```